# Updating ManyToMany Checkboxes PlayFramework 2

Tags: playframework, many-to-many, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, deadbolt

I have some troubles to update Many-To-Many Relationship with checkboxes in Play Framework 2.1.0

#### Account Model:

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "account_security_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "security_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
public List<SecurityRole> roles;
```

I want to update account roles in account edit view

#### Edit Account View:

```scala
@for(role <- SecurityRole.find.all()) {
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label"> @role.description </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <div class="text-toggle-button">
            <input type="checkbox" name="roles[@role.id].id" value="@role.id" class="toggle"
            @if(loggedAccount.hasHole(role.id)) {
               CHECKED
            } />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

So, when I call Update `POST` method I get this error:

> **InvalidPropertyException**: Invalid property `roles[3]` of bean class [`models.Account`]: Illegal attempt to get property `roles` threw exception; nested exception is `org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException`: Invalid property `roles` of bean class [`models.Account`]: Could not instantiate property type [`be.objectify.deadbolt.core.models.Role`] to auto-grow nested property path: `java.lang.InstantiationException`: `be.objectify.deadbolt.core.models.Role`

Is there some example to update a model using checkbox and Many-To-Many relationship?

Thanks a lot.
Lew

Comment: Can you give us the POST controller method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alban, I found the Error.

There is a convention for attribute names in models, so when a I change the name from **roles** to **securityRoles** It works fine and found the correct model class to instantiate.

#### Account Model:

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "account_security_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "security_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
public List<SecurityRole> securityRoles;
```

#### Edit Account View:

```scala
@for(role <- SecurityRole.find.all()) {
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label"> @role.description </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <div class="text-toggle-button">
            <input type="checkbox" name="securityRoles[@role.id].id" value="@role.id" class="toggle"
            @if(loggedAccount.hasHole(role.id)) {
               CHECKED
            } />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
}
```